# Swift - Mac OS - TIFF Image

Tags: swift, image, macos, assets, tiff

i have a question about how to work with tiff images in Swift (mac os).

What i want to achieve:

I got two tiff images(first.tif, second.tif), which i want to display in my mac os application.

```
let image: NSImage = NSImage(named: "first")! // fails here
let leftImageView: NSImageView = NSImageView(image: image)
self.view.addSubview(leftImageView)
```

With exception

```
CoreUI: attempting to lookup a named image 'first' with a type that is not a data type in the AssetCatalog
```

How to load tiff files in mac os?

Or should i completely change my strategy when it comes to work with tiff images?

Anybody can help me with this issue?

thanks and greetings

Comment: I created a simple Cocoa App and added `first.tif` to the project, and the first line of your code returns an `NSImage` with no problem. Please clarify the steps to reproduce the same issue you described.

Comment: i also created a new cocoa app, then i dropped first.tif to the assets folder and next inserted the line above in the viewdidload method, then the app crashes... really no idea what is going on..

Comment: this is my output: CoreUI: attempting to lookup a named image 'first' with a type that is not a data type in the AssetCatalog

Comment: There's no _assets folder_ in the newly created project. What do you mean by **dropped first.tif to the assets folder** ?

Comment: You mean the editing pane of Assets.xcassets ?

Comment: i mean: Assets.xcassets, i dropped my first.tif there

Comment: I see. I could have reproduced the same output as you describe. Remove the asset from Assets.xcassets, and add your first.tif to your project (somewhere in your project, but not in Assets.xcassets). As you have experienced, asset editor does not treat the extension ".tif" as an image resource.